# BeautifulSoup: Extract the text that is not in a given tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following variable, `header` equal to:

```
<p>Andrew Anglin<br/>
<strong>Daily Stormer</strong><br/>
February 11, 2017</p>
```

I want to extract from this variable only the date `February 11, 2017`.
How can I do it using BeautifulSoup in python?

Comment: You need to provide more of your html. This can be even achieved without BeautifulSoup. `html.split('\n')[-1][:-4]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the date is always the last text node in the header variable, then you could access the [`.contents` property](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) and get the last element in the returned list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
header = soup.find('p')

header.contents[-1].strip()
> February 11, 2017
```

Or, as [MYGz pointed out in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178348/beautifulsoup-extract-the-text-that-is-not-in-a-given-tag#comment71520429_42178430), you could split the text at new lines and retrieve the last element in the list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
header = soup.find('p')

header.text.split('\n')[-1]
> February 11, 2017
```

---

If you don't know the position of the date text node, then another option would be to parse out any matching strings:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
header = soup.find('p')

re.findall(r'\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}', header.text)[0]
> February 11, 2017
```

---

However, as your title implies, if you only want to retrieve text nodes that aren't wrapped with an element tag, then you could use the following which will filter out elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
header = soup.find('p')

text_nodes = [e.strip() for e in header if not e.name and e.strip()]
```

Keep in mind that would return the following since the first text node isn't wrapped:

```
> ['Andrew Anglin', 'February 11, 2017']
```

---

Of course you could also combine the last two options and parse out the date strings in the returned text nodes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
header = soup.find('p')

for node in header:
    if not node.name and node.strip():
        match = re.findall(r'^\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}$', node.strip())
        if match:
            print(match[0])

> February 11, 2017
```

---